Private Pension - UK Citizen, Moves Country Every Year
I am a UK citizen in my 30s that works in Academia. I have moved country for work almost every year for the past ~15 years. I regularly have to move country at short notice. Nowhere I have ever worked for has offered a workplace pension or similar, and usually I am technically not employed but paid as a contractor. I currently live in France, work in Switzerland and am paid by a Canadian university as a contractor.
I do not understand how to have savings or a pension in my situation. Whenever I look into savings accounts or private pensions they have rules that I have to be tax resident or similar. For an example this private pension seems good https://www.lloydsbank.com/pensions/ready-made-pension.html but under the requirements it says "you’re a UK taxpayer, you’re not a US person, and you’re under 74 years old".
How can I pay into a pension or similar in my situation?

I don't think you are going to find an easy solution for this.
The good news is that anybody can make payments into a savings fund for their retirement. The bad news is that unless you fulfil the tax residency requirements you aren't going to get a tax deduction for your contributions. The pension funds you are looking at are specifically designed to be tax deductible, which is why they are only open to British taxpayers. But you can start a non-deductible investment fund and make payments into it at any time, and use it for your retirement.
If you are resident in a country long enough to pay tax there it's likely there is a local tax-deductible way to make pension contributions. For example in Canada it's the RRSP. However most of these assume you will be resident in the country for a significant time, and there are penalties for withdrawing when you are not resident in the country (not punitive penalties, but enough to mean it often wasn't worth making the contribution anyway). If you are going to be resident in a country for a few years, ask the local tax experts.
The other way is to defer the whole tax-deductible pension question until you settle down. Make non-deductible investments, but as tax-friendly as possible world wide. Investing in something concrete like real estate is often a good way to go. Then when you decide to settle down in one country you have a sizeable lump sum to put into the pension scheme of that country. That will get you a very big tax break in the years you are doing it. Doing it gradually is best, so ideally settle down well before you want to retire.
And now I'm going to give you the most valuable piece of advice you will get as a British expat. I'm doing it last because you didn't strictly ask about it.
Make Class 2 Voluntary National Insurance Contributions. They are absolutely the best investment deal on the planet. For about a hundred pounds you can buy a whole year's credit to your UK state pension as if you had paid full NI. That's going to bump your UK state pension by about a hundred pounds, and you will get that extra every year after you are 67. Wherever you are in the world. Seriously, get a statement of your NI contributions now, and for every year where it says there were no contributions and you were abroad, arrange to make a back contribution. Then make a voluntary contribution every year until you return to the UK (if you ever do).
